# Win 2019 - VirtualBox Fatal: no bootable medium found! System Halted

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2019

I think I have tried everything on this question to no avail: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fatal-no-bootable-medium-found-system-halted-virtualbox

I upgraded to Virtual Box 6.1.  Below are my choices for IDE - I tried all 3 of them, and for each I tried both orders of boot order: disk first vs Optical First. I did not try making the hard drive an IDE though.

[image]

This is the file I downloaded from Microsoft: mu_windows_server_2019_language_pack_x64_dvd_679192ff.iso (2,831,929,344 bytes). Can anyone confirm if it's bootable and the correct media?

Comment: You have a storage controller, but where is the virtual hard disk?

Comment: Isn't BizTalk2020.vdi the hard disk? I went through the new item wizard to create the virtual box, and told it I wanted a 50 Gig dynamic disk drive.

Comment: Also the optical drive is set as "IDE Primary Master" and Live CD/DVD is checked.

Comment: I'm thinking I only downloaded the language pack, not the actual install.

Comment: I downloaded SQL Server and BizTalk server, but I'm about 90% convinced now that I don't have Windows Server itself in my MSDN VisualStudio subscription, I'll have to check with someone else at my company to get that.

Comment: @NealWalters - You downloaded a language pack.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line is that I didn't have a bootable image. The Win 2019 language pack is not the 2019 Operating System.

The correct file downloaded today was:

> en_windows_server_2019_updated_march_2019_x64_dvd_2ae967ab.iso

and is over 5 gig, where as the language pack was only about 2 gig.  Some MSDN subscriptions only have the language pack, but others have the full operating systems, depending on your subscription.